# Unable to list Nomad job/task logs despite being able to submit Nomad job (using same token to authenticate)

Tags: hashicorp-vault, nomad

I am using Vault for secrets management to generate short-lived Nomad ACL tokens with which my deployment agent (GoCD) can authenticate against Nomad:

```sh
vault read -field=secret_id nomad/creds/gocd
```

My ACL policy for `gocd` is:

```
namespace "default" {
  policy = "write"
}
```

I am using GoCD to submit Nomad jobs for deployment:

```sh
nomad job run {{ temp_directory.path }}/{{ service_name }}.nomad
```

Both of the above steps work as expected. However, when I try to get the logs of a failed Nomad deployment using

```sh
nomad alloc logs -token {{ nomad_token.stdout }} -job {{ service_name }} {{ task_name }}
```

I am getting

```sh
"Error reading file: Unexpected response code: 403 (Permission denied)"
```

According to the Nomad [documentation](https://www.nomadproject.io/guides/security/acl.html#namespace-rules), the `"write"` policy includes the `"read-logs"` capability.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a `"read"` policy for `node` in my ACL policy did the trick:

```
namespace "default" {
  policy = "write"
}

node {
  policy = "read"
}
```

The problem I was facing is explained well in an existing GitHub [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/5754).